# Sending URLs using a loop- Eclipse Java Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have a jsp program that receives 5 parameters.

Each parameter can have 8 values and I need to test all the combinations. The output of this program is stored in a file.

Changing the parameters manually takes a very a long time, is there a way to automate this? For example a script that contains three loops and wait for the execution of the previous URL to finish before going to the next combination.

I am using Eclipse and Tomcat server.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the answer, it is helpful. But I am not trying to do end-to-end testing. I am running an experiment and trying to find the correlation between different parameters. That's why I need to do this. I know that the components of my program work fine, I just wanted to accelerate the process. 

As I said in the other thread, my question is fairly stupid. Why sending parameters when I know the values upfront. I just added the loops I need in doGet that changes the value.

But still, your answer is very helpful, thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome nonetheless. And you are right, maybe someone else can find something helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question translates to an insufficient understanding of different testing concepts.

You are asking how you could do proper end-to-end testing for your complete "service" with all potential input parameters.

That is not required at all. To the contrary: you should focus on good unit tests for the different components involved.

Such unit tests are easy to automate, and concepts such as junit rules even allow for sophisticated handling of input parameter testing.

And then when you are convinced that your different components all work, you only need a few end-to-end tests to prove that your "plumbing" is correct!